# Specify sub-parameter of JSON for datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to populate a datatable via ajax JSON. These are arrays labeled in the JSON as `instances`:

```
{"success":true,"subs":null,"instances":[{"strategy":"284","exchange":"3","uptime":77093},{"strategy":"284","exchange":"3","uptime":6300}],"pl":[{"exchange":"0.00000000"},{"exchange":"0.00000000"}],"botInstances":[{"id":"1","userId":"1","product":"284","exchange":"3","trades":"0","startTime":"1532834112","pl":"0.00000000"},{"id":"2","userId":"1","product":"284","exchange":"3","trades":"0","startTime":"1532904905","pl":"0.00000000"}]}
```

And here's the code:

```js
var table1 = jQuery('#tablepress-1').DataTable({
"bDestroy": false,
"bProcessing": false,
"ajax": {
  "url": "/api/?action=getBotStats",
  "datacSrc": "",
  "success": function(result){
   data = result['instances'];
  }
},
"columns": [{
    "data": "strategy"
  },
  {
    "data": "exchange"
  },
  {
    "data": "trades"
  },
  {
    "data": "pl"
  },
  {
    "data": "uptime"
  }
],
"columnDefs": [{
    "title": "Strategy",
    "targets": 0
  },
  {
    "title": "Exchange",
    "targets": 1
  },
  {
    "title": "Trades",
    "targets": 2
  },
  {
    "title": "P&L",
    "targets": 3
  },
  {
    "title": "Uptime",
    "targets": 4
  }
]
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table id="tablepress-1" class="tablepress tablepress-id-1 dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="tablepress-1_info">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tablepress-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 235px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Strategy: activate to sort column descending">Strategy</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tablepress-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 272px;" aria-label="Exchange: activate to sort column ascending">Exchange</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tablepress-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 201px;" aria-label="Trades: activate to sort column ascending">Trades</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tablepress-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 146px;" aria-label="P&amp;L: activate to sort column ascending">P&amp;L</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tablepress-1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 206px;" aria-label="Uptime: activate to sort column ascending">Uptime</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty" valign="top">Loading...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to get this running in the snippet thing but it didn't work out so great (I don't use fiddles often). There's no longer an error but the table doesn't populate.

Comment: Edited to represent the actual table markup. It was incorrect before.

Comment: Edited to use zAnthony's solution but table still doesn't populate.

Comment: [success - Must not be overridden as it is used internally in DataTables. To manipulate / transform the data returned by the server use ajax.dataSrc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) ...So remove `success` and use **`dataSrc: function(data) {...}`** to return a fixed dataset. However, impossible to know how you want to combine the different sections in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem before. I solved it using the datatables `dataFilter` param.

As far as I know, `dataFilter` let's you modify the response from your server before rendering the data into datatables column.

Here's the sample code.

```
table.DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        'ajax': {
            'url': url,
            'type': 'GET',
            'beforeSend': function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", serial);
            },
            'dataFilter': function (data) {
                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                json.recordsTotal = json.totalElements;
                json.recordsFiltered = json.numberOfElements;
                json.data = json.content;

                return JSON.stringify(json); // return JSON string
            }
        },
        "columns": [{
                "data": "strategy"
            },
            {
                "data": "exchange"
            },
            {
                "data": "trades"
            },
            {
                "data": "pl"
            },
            {
                "data": "uptime"
            }
        ],
    });
```

Take note that I was using datatables as `server side` = `true`. I don't know if it's the same/will work in your situation.

Answer (score -1):

Try modifying your ajax call to get the data:

```
var table1 = jQuery('#tablepress-1').DataTable({
"bDestroy": false,
"bProcessing": false,
"ajax": {
"url": "/api/?action=getBotStats",
"datacSrc": ""
 "success": function (result) {
        data = result;
      }
},
....continue as you have in your code...
```

Comment: I don't get any errors now but it's still not populating the table.

Comment: modify to assign the entire result to the data field and then parse it as need.  For example, data["instances"].strategy, data["exchange"], data["pl"].exchange.   Because you have a mutli array dataset in your result, you need to know how to parse it and assign it to the correct columns.

Comment: Can you show me what that looks like? This is my first time using datatables and I thought that when I used the `column` directive I was mapping elements from `data`. So do I do it on the left side or the right side?